# Is the following statement true/false ?..

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement  true/false ?

> The function $f$ defined  by

> $f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x} ,x >0\\ 0, x \le 0 \end{cases}$

> is differentiable for all real  value of  $x$

**My attempt** : I think this  statement is false

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-1/h}}{h} \neq \lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{e^{-1/h}}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{e^{-1/h}}{h}=\lim_{h\to-\infty}he^{-h}=\lim_{h\to-\infty}\left(h-h^2+\frac{h^3}{2!}-\dots\right)=-\infty$$

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{e^{-1/h}}{h}=0$$

The Left hand derivative and the Right hand derivative at a point  $0$ are not equal

Comment: $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-1/h}}{h} \neq \lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{e^{-1/h}}{h}$ is irrelevant here. Think about $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x)/x$ and $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)/x$ instead.

Comment: @Koro If the Left hand derivative and the Right hand derivative at a point are equal then the function is said to be differentiable at that point.

Comment: Your left derivative is wrong:$$
     \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \dfrac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \dfrac{0 - 0}{h} = 0
$$
since $f(h) = 0 \ \forall h < 0$

Comment: See function is $0$ for all $(-\infty, 0]$ so you have to check only for right hand side.

Comment: @jasmine: That's true indeed. The function that needs to be considered in the sentence that you wrote is $f$ and not e^{,}.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that makes sense

Comment: @jasmine just see this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/85o8bsjqgy to visualize how your function looks like :)

Comment: Not only is this claim true, but in fact the function is infinitely differentiable, even at $0$. This (or similar variants) is an extremely useful function in analysis and differential geometry.